# Facebook insights graph API, permanent token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph, laravel-5, token

I'm making a statistics widget in PHP (using laravel 5.1). I need to pull some data from the Facebook insights graph API. I need to get some data that requires read_insights permission, so I need to pass an access_token.

My question is - how do I (serverside, no client auth possible) get an access token that works permanently?

Right now I only got it to work by grabbing my users token from Facebooks graph explorer, but obviously this token only has a short lifetime.

The insights data I need to grab, is from a Facebook page. Doesn't a page just have a secret key or something, I can pass, in order to get access?

Example if the current HTTP request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/{pageid}/insights/page_impressions?access_token={token}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- Autorize with `manage_pages` and `read_insights`.
- Extend the User Token.
- Call `/me/accounts` to get Extended Page Tokens for your Pages. It is valid forever.

How to extend a User Token is explained in the docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: Hi luschn, thanks for your fast reply.

Isn't it possible to make the auth non-user based? The widget must be flexible and easy to adjust to pull data from a different page at any time. This means that each client must give my user access. Would be much nicer, if no user was required, and it's just pure page-based authing.

In the docs I see this: 
"A page access token with read_insights permission can retrieve all metrics for that Page."

I guess a page access token, is what I need? But I can't figure out where go get/generate one.

Comment: of course not, that would be weird if you could just grab the insights without any user context - how else would facebook know you are allowed to see the insights?

Comment: you could also just read the docs, i don´t add links to my answers just for fun: "To obtain a page access token you need to start by obtaining a user access token and asking for the manage_pages permission"